# mariadb jdbc не работает - No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/statsDB

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb

Пытаюсь подключиться к **mariadb** через **jbdc** отсюда:
`https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/about-mariadb-connector-j/`.

Из кода пока только строчка:
`DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/statsDB");`

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы собираете проект maven'ом, то в зависимостях необходимо указать драйвер.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
    <version>xxx</version>
</dependency>
```

Ошибка четко говорит, что не может найти драйвер для данного url адреса. Посмотрите еще раз внимательно [статью об установке драйвера](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/getting-started-with-the-java-connector/)